# How to spread month to day with amount value divided by total days per month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, days, dateadd

I have data with an amount of 1 month and want to change it to 30 days.
if 1 month the amount is `20000` then per day is `666.67`

The following are sample data and results:

| Account | Project | Date | Segment | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Acc1 | 1 | September 2022 | Actual | 20000 |

Result :

[image]

I need a query using sql server

Comment: `"if 1 month the amount is 20000 then per day is 666.67"` Do note that `666.67 X 30 = 20,000.01` does not equal to the original amount of `20,000`

Comment: So you want to create 30 rows out of 1. What if the month has 28/29/31 days?

Comment: If I choose January then 31 days, February then 29 and so on following the number of days in a month

Answer (score 1):

You may try a set-based approach using an appropriate number table and a calculation with windowed `COUNT()`.

Data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   ('Acc1', 1, CONVERT(date, '20220901'),  'Actual',  20000.00)
) v (Account, Project, [Date], Segment, Amount)
```

Statement for all versions, starting from SQL Server 2016 (the number table is generated using JSON-based approach with `OPENJSON()`):

```
SELECT d.Account, d.Project, a.[Date], d.Segment, a.Amount
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT 
    d.Amount / COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), 
    DATEADD(day, CONVERT(int, [key]), d.[Date])
  FROM OPENJSON('[1' + REPLICATE(',1', DATEDIFF(day, d.[Date], EOMONTH(d.[Date]))) + ']')
) a (Amount, Date)
```

Statement for SQL Server 2022 (the number table is generated with `GENERATE_SERIES()`):

```
SELECT d.Account, d.Project, a.[Date], d.Segment, a.Amount
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT 
    d.Amount / COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), 
    DATEADD(day, [value], d.[Date])
  FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, DATEDIFF(day, d.[Date], EOMONTH(d.[Date])))
) a (Amount, Date)
```

Notes:

- Both approaches calculate the days for each month. If you always want 30 days per month, replace `DATEDIFF(day, d.[Date], EOMONTH(d.[Date]))` with `29`.
- There is a rounding issue with this calculation. You may need to implement an additional calculation for the last day of the month.

Comment: Thank you @Zhorov. this is very helpful, the explanation is very detailed

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate each day of the month and then divide the amount by the number of days in the month to achive the required output

```
DECLARE @Amount NUMERIC(18,2) = 20000,
        @MonthStart DATE = '2022-09-01'

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        CurrentDate = @MonthStart,
        DayAmount = CAST(@Amount/DAY(EOMONTH(@MonthStart)) AS NUMERIC(18,2)),
        RemainingAmount =  CAST(@Amount - (@Amount/DAY(EOMONTH(@MonthStart))) AS NUMERIC(18,2))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CurrentDate = DATEADD(DAY,1,CurrentDate),
        DayAmount = CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY,1,CurrentDate) = EOMONTH(@MonthStart)
                                THEN RemainingAmount
                            ELSE DayAmount END,
        RemainingAmount = CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY,1,CurrentDate) = EOMONTH(@MonthStart)
                                THEN 0 
                            ELSE CAST(RemainingAmount-DayAmount AS NUMERIC(18,2)) END
        FROM CTE
            WHERE CurrentDate < EOMONTH(@MonthStart)
)
SELECT
    CurrentDate,
    DayAmount
    FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want an equal split without rounding errors and without loops you can use this calculation. It spreads the rounding error across all entries, so they are all as equal as possible.

```
DECLARE @Amount NUMERIC(18,2) = 20000,
        @MonthStart DATE = '20220901'

SELECT DATEADD(DAY,Numbers.i - 1,@MonthStart)
     , ShareSplit.Calculated_Share
     , SUM(ShareSplit.Calculated_Share) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Calculated_Total
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT number FROM master..spt_values WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND DAY(EOMONTH(@MonthStart)))Numbers(i)
 CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(ROUND(@Amount * 100 / DAY(EOMONTH(@MonthStart)),0) * 0.01
             + CASE
                  WHEN Numbers.i
                       <= ABS((@Amount - (ROUND(@Amount * 100 / DAY(EOMONTH(@MonthStart)),0) / 100.0 * DAY(EOMONTH(@MonthStart)))) * 100)
                       THEN 0.01 * SIGN(@Amount - (ROUND(@Amount * 100 / DAY(EOMONTH(@MonthStart)),0) / 100.0 * DAY(EOMONTH(@MonthStart))))
                  ELSE 0
               END AS DEC(18,2)) AS Calculated_Share
       )ShareSplit
```